# Jetpack Compose: Text is not wrapped. It is truncated. Why?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am showing a list of books. The title of the book is supposed to wrap when it does not fit the available width. I have specified 3 max lines but it does not seem to help. Am I missing some steps?
Text widget is inside a ConstraintLayout. I tried to set the end of the title to the end of the parent but that causes the text to overlap with the image.
Please see the screenshot for details.

[image: Screenshot]

```
            ConstraintLayout(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(backgroundColor)
                    .padding(4.dp)
            ) {
                val (image, titleConst, authorConst) = createRefs()
                val imageEnd = createEndBarrier(image)
                AsyncImage(
                    model = book.bookImage, modifier = Modifier
                        .constrainAs(image) {
                            top.linkTo(parent.top)
                            start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                        }
                        .width(imageWidth.dp)
                        .height(height.dp),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.book_cover)
                )

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(titleConst) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 8.dp)
                        start.linkTo(image.end, margin = 8.dp)
                        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    },
                    text = title,
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    color = textColor,
                    maxLines = 3,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(authorConst) {
                        top.linkTo(titleConst.bottom, margin = 4.dp)
                        start.linkTo(titleConst.start, margin = 0.dp)
                        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                        //end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 8.dp)
                    },
                    text = author,
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = textColor,
                    maxLines = 3,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out the documentation of [`fillToConstraints`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/constraintlayout/compose/Dimension#fillToConstraints()):

> A Dimension that spreads to match constraints.

You have to both specify the left and right edge constraints of the Text Composable to make it work. So please try to change your Text Composable as follows:

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(titleConst) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 8.dp)
        start.linkTo(image.end, margin = 8.dp)
        end.linkTo(parent.end)  // explicitly specify this
        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
    },
    // ...
)
```

See also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77023280/android-compose-contraintlayout-has-a-text-inside-which-if-its-long-it-will) for reference.